# How to select an enum to a new list?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

```
var menuQuery = repository.MenuMasters.OrderBy(c => c.Position).Select(c => new { ID = c.MenuMasterID, Position = (MenuItemPosition)c.Position + " - " + c.SitePage.Title });
ViewBag.ParentID = new SelectList(menuQuery, "ID", "Position", selectedParentId);


public int Position { get; set; }
    public MenuItemPosition MenuPosition {
        get { return (MenuItemPosition)Position; }
        set { Position = (int)value; }
    }

public enum MenuItemPosition {
    Top = 1, Main = 2, Footer = 3
}
```

I got an error which said "Unable to cast the type 'Type Name' to type 'Type Name'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types."

MenuItemPosition is "Enum", Title is "string"

How can I fix this? Many thanks~!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add `.ToList` after OrderBy, as string concatenation is not supported with Linq to Entities.. So your query will look something like :

```
var menuQuery = repository.MenuMasters.OrderBy(c => c.Position).ToList().Select(c => new { ID = c.MenuMasterID, Position = ((MenuItemPosition)c.Position).convertToString() + " - " + c.SitePage.Title });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
var menuQuery = repository.MenuMasters.OrderBy(c => c.Position).Select(c => new { ID = c.MenuMasterID, Position = c.Position.ToString() + " - " + c.SitePage.Title });
```

Comment: what do you really want to put there enum name? can you update your question with the enum